# Lightweight Kotlin library for JSON parsing which allows floating point not-a-number (NaN)

Tags: json, kotlin

I am looking for a lightweight JSON parser for Kotlin which allows floating point not-a-number (NaN). I only need to parse JSON to a map of key/value pairs, with the keys being strings and the values being Kotlin types, such as string, int, double, and map, and not JSON element types; I don't want to have to do a round of coercion or conversion on the return values to get something I can work with in the program. Also, I don't need, and don't want, a parser which maps JSON documents onto class instances.

To recap, these are the requirements I'm looking for.

- Kotlin
- JSON parser
- returns a map of key/value pairs; keys are strings, values are Kotlin types (e.g., string, int, double, list, map)
- parser recognizes and allows floating point NaN

It would be great if a JSON parser handles that stuff out of the box, but if some minimal configuration is needed, I can work with that too.